# How does an electron move around as a wave in orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, atoms, orbitals

This question arose when I was told that there were positive and negative lobes in an orbital. I wanted to know on what basis this was proposed and hence I searched it on web and found out that it resembled the phases of the wave. But I always thought of orbital as a 2-d racing circuit for the electron, in which the electron would race around while bobbing up and down. Hence I wanted to know whether the p-orbital is the wave itself or is it like a racing circuit?

Here is my attempt to explain it visually! (Great graphics? Thank you!)[image]

Conclusion : Electrons don't have position. They are called particles only because they show nature of particles. Since they don't have position and are not particles, then there is actually no reason to visualize their path. They are neither particles nor waves but a mix of them. (If there is something wrong about the conclusion, then feel free to comment below)

Comment: I think your conclusion is correct but for the part: „They are waves“. Without knowing it for sure, I am *pretty* sure that the wave function (which comprises everything we can know about the electron) is not what makes the electron a wave. The electron is as much *not* a wave as it is *not* a particle. Depending on the experimental setup it shows aspects of a particle or aspects of a wave.

Comment: This explains that the orbit is a standing 3D wave of the electron about the nucleus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital. Thus the electron does not orbit the nucleus like a planet (or particle). The wave function describes the probability of interacting with the electron at a particle point during measurement, *not* the probability that the electron is at a particular point.

Comment: I think that should fix it @HartmutBraun

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted to know whether the p-orbital is the wave itself or is it like a racing circuit?

The p-orbital is the wave itself. It is a standing wave that reflects off of the confining potential well of the Coulomb attraction to the nucleus. If you take a cut through the $y,z$ plane, it looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<sup>Mathematica source: `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbGmb.png"]`</sup>

Here the vertical axis is the 'probability amplitude' (i.e. the wavefunction, $\psi(x,y,z)$).

You get the standard peanut shape if you compute the squared-modulus $|\psi(x,y,z)|^2$ and you plot a contour at a fixed value halfway between the minimum and the maximum, either in 2D or 3D.

The "racing circuit" you have drawn has no relation to reality. To the extent that it can be made to work is by having the "racing circuit" go in a straight line up and down the $z$ axis, with a wavelength equal to the length of the circuit. (But that is a fragile mental model, and it is extremely liable to cause additional errors and misconceptions, so use it as sparingly as possible.)

Comment: So orbitals are waves?? Correct me if I am wrong but I have been taught that orbitals are the places where electrons reside, ie. maximum probability. So if they are the places with maximum probability of finding an electron then how can they be waves?

Comment: Language can be bent and re-used as required by the context. In 'grown-up' QM, orbitals are waves, period. (They come with uniquely-associated probability distributions and thus with locations of maximal probability, but what they *are* is waves.) The simplification you have been told is a useful teaching tool, but you need to treat it as such.

Comment: So the pictures of the orbitals  s, p and d were a lie?

Comment: No, pictures like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png) are accurate representations of the probability densities ($|\psi(\mathbf r)|^2$) that arise from the wavefunctions of the orbitals ($\psi(\mathbf r)$). It's just important to pay attention to what's being claimed that they are.

Comment: @Humble_Snowman they are the equivalent of drawing stick figures in place of a full human form. It’s not a lie,  but it’s not the whole truth.

Comment: Ok so I read a lot more about the orbitals thingy. I read that in p orbital, electron is in a specific phase (+?) in one lobe and another phase (-?) in the other lobe. What does this mean? I think this will hopefully mark the end of this question.

Comment: @Humble_Snowman That's for a separate thread.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Do the orbitals represent modes of the *electron* wave (with de Broglie wavelength) or modes of a higher level *electron position* wave? When you say that it "is the wave itself," it seems to imply the former, that the de Broglie wavelength characterizes the orbital. Is this correct?

Comment: @jpf That distinction looks like meaningless semantics to me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Please understand I'm not insinuating you're wrong; my question is genuine. The distinction is the difference between the top illustration and the bottom in the OP question (assuming in 3D). In the top illustration, the electron has it's own wavelength independent (except for boundary condition) of the superimposed wave of its position about the bound atom. Is this the meaning of the orbital wave, or is the orbital wave represented by the bottom illustration, which reflects only possible configurations of the de Broglie wave wrapped upon itself?

Comment: @jpf Ask separately. I'm uninterested in this discussion.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I believe I've simply rephrased the original question that highlights what's missing in the answers, but fine.

Answer (score 2):

In quantum mechanics electron in general has no position. It is not that we do not know what is the position, it literally has no such property. Kind of like color has no taste. It makes no sense to talk about position of electron (in general), just like it makes no sense to talk about taste of color blue.  So the picture of racing electrons is just wrong.

All we can say is what probability is to find electron at certain area. Orbital is simply put just wave function that encodes this probability if it would be filled by some electron.

The pictures of orbitals you can see are just areas of space, where the probability density of finding the electron there is bigger than certain number - if it would be filled.

**Answering the comment:**

> "...electron has no position..." seems to contradict "...we can say the probability to find electron at certain area..."

it only seems that way. It has not position before the collapse of the wave function, but it has immediately after the collapse. The measurement forces the electron to take up the position.

Comment: hmm.. so here is a doubt. If the pictures of orbitals I see are just areas of space where prob density of finding the electron are highest then what do the positive and negative lobes of the orbital mean in this context?

Comment: @Humble_Snowman As far as I know, these concern phase of the p-orbital when you have two atoms. It has no meaning for orbital by itself,  Negative lobes simply mean, the two areas of two orbitals of these two atoms are out of phase.

Comment: @Humble_Snowman The wave function can have positive and negative values, but either way when you take the square modulus you get a real positive number.

Comment: "...electron has no position..." seems to contradict "...we can say the probability to find electron at certain area..."

Comment: @jpf it only seems that way. It has not position before the collapse of the wave function, but it has immediately after the collapse. The measurement forces the electron to take up the position.

Comment: @Umaxo This qualification is important; otherwise neither statement is correct.

Comment: @jpf I do not believe so as having position and being able to measure position are very different things in QM. But I will add the clarification to the end.

Answer (score -1):

We don't have a model of an electron but we know that its charge is essentially concentrated in a point. Its dynamics is however described by a wave, the wave function, which is a solution to Schrodinger's wave equation. For an electron in the coulomb potential of a nucleus this equation has discrete solutions, orbitals, that describe bound states.